# Puhser Beam ontap notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, pusher

For push notifications, I'm using the pusher_beams: ^1.1.1 package in flutter. I am receiving the notification. When I select the notification when the application is closed or running in the background, I have to navigate to that specific screen.

onMessageReceivedInTheForeground() and getInitialMessage() method only available.